# Finding the multiples of 3 in a given range

Tags: python

I wrote a code that can find the multiples of 3 of a given number, but I want to make it so that it will only print out the multiples of 3 in a given range. How can I do that?

Here's my code:

```
def findMultiples(x):
   for x in range(1, x + 1):
      if x % 3 == 0 
         print(x)

findMultiples(120)
```

Comment: Could you clarify a.) what the purpose of `x % 5 == 0` is, and b.) what you mean by a "range". Do you want to modify the function to take in an additional lower and upper bound?

Comment: Hey bruv, look like you dunnit innit?  Whass wiv dis x % 5 anyhow?

Comment: I meant so that if I give gave it a range like 1, 11, it will only pirnt out the multiple of 3 in that range.

Comment: Having `x % 3 == 0 and x % 5 == 0` is equivalent to `x % 15 == 0`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to loop through every number to see if it's a multiple of 3. Once you've found one, you can step through multiples only.

```
def findMultiples(x, y, multiple):
    # find the first value that's a multiple
    for i in range(x, x + multiple):
        if i % multiple == 0:
            break
    # step through the remaining values
    for j in range(i, y, multiple):
        print(j)

findMultiples(121, 143, 3)
```

```
123
126
129
132
135
138
141
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def findMultiples(x, y):
   for i in range(x, y + 1):
      if i % 3 == 0 and i % 5 == 0:
         print(i)

findMultiples(120, 240)
```

I still don't sure what do you mean, but I think this is what you want. In your `for` loop, you set the wrong loop variable, it should be anything else than `x`.

Comment: Also you should remove the `i % 5 == 0`, that's unecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Use another variable name in for loop ("i" for example):

```py
def findMultiples(x):
   for i in range(1, x + 1):
      if i % 3 == 0:
         print(i)
         
findMultiples(120)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter function
The 1st argument is the function based on which filtering will happen `lambda x: x%3==0` returns True or False for an input x. The input x comes from the list `[i for i in range(a, b)]` which is the 2nd argument to the filter function.

```
>>> a = 100
>>> b = 200
>>> print(list(filter( lambda x:x%3==0 , [i for i in range(a, b)])))
[102, 105, 108, 111, 114, 117, 120, 123, 126, 129, 132, 135, 138, 141, 144, 147, 150, 153, 156, 159, 162, 165, 168, 171, 174, 177, 180, 183, 186, 189, 192, 195, 198]
```